# How to fix this comparing strings( from argv and scanf) program?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, strstr

Trying to fix this program that compares words found through argv and ones from scanf(). If the same word is found, it prints "CENSORED" and if not, just prints the word. For example, I have a file called beatles.txt that has the following words:
paul 
ringo
george
john

If I compile this program and test it like this:
./a.out ringo < beatles.txt ,
This is the output:

CENSORED
ringo
CENSORED
ringo
CENSORED
ringo

Whereas, I want this to be the output:

paul
CENSORED
george
john

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

char word_arr[10000][20];
int i=0;

while ( scanf("%s",word_arr[i])!=EOF) {

    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {

        if (strstr(word_arr[i],argv[i]) != NULL) {

            printf("CENSORED\n");
        }

        else {

            printf("%s\n",word_arr[i]);

        }

    }
i++;

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Offtopic for SO.

Comment: The inner `i` is shadowing the outer `i`. Pick another name for one of those identifiers.

Comment: Please don't make the correction to the code posted. It becomes a non-question. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

As @WeatherVane observes,

> The inner `i` is shadowing the outer `i`. Pick another name for one of those identifiers.

Here is one way to do this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char word_arr[10000][20];
    int j = 0;

    while (scanf("%s", word_arr[j]) != EOF) {
        bool is_censored = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            if (strstr(word_arr[j], argv[i])) {
                printf("CENSORED ");
                is_censored = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!is_censored) printf("%s ", word_arr[j]);
        j++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't notice that. This made it work but only if I try it with one name as scanf input. If I do something like ./a.out john ringo <beatles.txt, the output is still kindof messed up. It prints: paul
paul
ringo
CENSORED
george
george
CENSORED
john, whereas I want the output to be paul CENSORED george CENSORED

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. I have one last question: Let's just say I have a file with 3 sentences (3 different lines). When I run this code, It makes it all just one sentence. How do I change this? If I put a "\n" after "%s", it makes every single word a new line. Any clue how I can accomplish this and not alter the sentence structure in the files?

Comment: Oh, John, I'll leave that modification as an exercise. You can do it. I have faith in you. Good luck.